# Caldav server - polled too frequently

Tags: server, caldav

I have an application for group scheduling that serves a Caldav feed to members. It's very simple - on request, just grabs upcoming events for that member, formats the stream, returns it. Some members are using devices that poll much too frequently - things don't update that often - so I'm hitting my database more often than I need to.

I can obviously cache the formatted stream and just update it no more frequently than I feel like it. It would be easier to return some kind of "ask me later" response to someone who has polled recently. Is there such a response? If I just don't return a stream, will the client read that as a "there are no events" response?

thanks!

Comment: How exactly do they poll? Polling frequently is not really an issue for the CalDAV server if proper etag/ctag/dav-sync queries are run as the poll (it just has to compare a few bytes ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably fix the original reason why clients are polling 'too frequently'. What does 'too frequently' mean for you? Do they send a proper etag/sync-token so that the polling is cheap?

Regardless, there is indeed an HTTP status for that: [HTTP 503](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.4).

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   **Retry-After** header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

Now the question is how many HTTP clients actually deal with that properly, but I do know some which do :-)